# How to echo/print actual file contents on a unix system

Tags: linux, unix, text, ascii

I would like to see the actual file contents without it being formatted to print. For example, to show:

```
\n0.032,170\n0.034,290
```

Instead of:

```
0.032,170
0.34,290
```

Is there a command to echo the file's actual data in bash? I've tried using `head`, `cat`, `more`, etc. but all those seem to echo the "print-formatted" text. For example:

```
$ cat example.csv
0.032,170
0.34,290
```

How can I print the actual characters within the file?

Comment: `\n` is not the "actual character" in the file.  It is a string representation used to display a particular octet.

Comment: `hexdump` and some of its formating options or simply `hd` may help you

Comment: `cat -A file` will show you something. `less -U` also but less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads as if you miss understand what the "actual characters in the file" are. You will not find the characters `\` and `n` in that file. But only a line feed, which is a specific character. So the utilities like cat do actually output exactly the characters in the file.

Putting it the other way around: if you really had those two characters literally in the file, then a utility like cat would actually output them. I just checked that, just to be sure.

You can easily check that yourself if you open the file using a hexeditor. There you will see the character 0A (decimal 10) which is a line feed character. You will *not* see the pair of the two characters `\` and `n` somewhere in that file.

Many programming languages and also shell environments use escape sequences like `\n` in string definitions and identify those as control characters which would not be typable otherwise. So maybe that is where your impression comes from that your files should contain those two characters.

Comment: here is what I would do in python, for example, opening it in binary mode: `>>> open('example.csv','r+b').read()
b'distance,recession_velocity\r\n# not a row,\r\n0.032,170\r\n0.034,290\r\n0.214,-130\r\n0.263,-70\r\n0.275,-185\r\n0.275,-220\r\n0.4,200\r\n0.5,290\r\n0.5,270\r\n0.6,200\r\n0.8,300\r\n0.9,-30\r\n0.9,650\r\n0.9,150\r\n0.9,500\r\n1,920\r\n1.1,450\r\n1.1,500\r\n1.4,500\r\n1.7,960\r\n2,500\r\n2,850\r\n2,800\r\n2,1090\r\n# Total,527'`

Comment: Yep, that is what I meant with my past paragraph. You define a string there which is interpreted. It is not the sequences of a backslash and a letter that is actually defined in the string, but what the interpreter makes from that control sequence.

Comment: Have a try and check yourself using a hexeditor, as I suggested. `Okteta` is a nice one, but many exist.

Comment: got it, I'll check out Okteta. Is there a way to print the binary data of the file then?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "print the binary data". There is a character sequence the file contains. That is what utilities like `cat` output. There is no difference between "binary data" and "normal data" inside a file. That is a question of how data is interpreted in certain environments who do or do not interpret certain control sequences one way or another. But that is not a feature of the file itself somehow. That contains just characters and it is just a file.

Comment: I guess my question is this then: is there a command I can do in unix such as `$ <command> example.csv` where the literal output (as if I took a screenshot of the output) showed `\n0.032,170\n0.034,290` ? It's required for me to find separators and linebreaks in a csv file -- which I'm now using python to do currently.

Comment: Well, not really, you could only replace the line feed characters to an escape sequence again, so something like `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' testfile`...

Comment: @David542 If you find that replacing linefeeds with C escape sequences is helpful in parsing CSV files, you're doing something extremely strange that can probably be dramatically simplified.

Comment: @David542 . `awk 1 ORS='\\n' input-file`

Answer (score 0):

To display newlines as `\n`, you might try:

```
awk 1 ORS='\\n' input-file
```

This is *not* the "actual characters in the file", as `\n` is merely a conventional method of displaying a newline, but this does seem to be what you want.